# Android query can't store class variable from JSON object callback

Tags: android, json, ajax, callback, aquery

I can't write class variable from AJAX-JSON callback. It show right info inside callback but when a Query callback finishes, it is set to null. Why?

This is code:

```
public void asyncJson() {

    String url = "myurl";
    aq.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status
        { 
            if (json != null) {
                jsonToString(json);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

private void jsonToString(JSONObject data) {
    JSONArray array = null;
    try {
        array = data.getJSONArray("listResp");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = array.getJSONObject(i);

            c.setDate_creation(json_data.getString("date_creation"));
            c.setName_user(json_data.getString("name_user"));

            list.add(c);//linkedlist
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The variable `listContest` when callback finishes is null.

Comment: There is no variable `listContest` in the code you have posted.

Comment: sorry! i've modified now! is the variable list! (linkedList)

Comment: Still confused. What's null here? Do you get a NullPointerException? Then post the stack trace. Also show where you declare and initialize `list`.

Comment: I initialize it on the OnCreate of the activity, no error in logcat! It seem strange..as if the callback turn null all used variable!

Comment: Ok, so how do you know it's null? I can't see any code checking it. Where and when is what null.

Comment: I debug it! After method finish it returns null...

Comment: Neither method you have posted return anything, they're `void` methods.

Comment: Ok. I re-ask a question. How can i wait callback finish, before assign the value to the class variable?